# mysql pivot help using date vaule

Tags: mysql, pivot

I am starting off in sql and have already run into an issue.
I can create a temp table just fine with the data i need that shows the hours worked by a user on a given date range... the dates will vary
and i get this ...

```
User hours worked_date
Bill  8     01-04-17
Bill  6     02-04-17
Bob   7     01-04-17
```

However i need to do this...

```
User  01-04-17  02-04-17
Bill    8         6
bob     7
```

i can do this in ms access with no trouble but I cant get it work in mysql.. and the help guides leave me lost.  any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Lea

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's nothing similar to MS Access's `TRANSFORM ... PIVOT` statement in MySQL, but you can leverage dynamic SQL to achieve the goal.

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN worked_date = ''', worked_date,
                ''' THEN hours END) `', worked_date, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM table1 
                    GROUP BY user');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| User | 2017-01-04 | 2017-02-04 |
|------|------------|------------|
| Bill |          8 |          6 |
|  Bob |          7 |     (null) |
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dc49/4)

---

You can wrap it up in a stored procedure to simplify things in your client code

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE user_worked_hours()
BEGIN
    SET @sql = NULL;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
             CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN worked_date = ''', worked_date,
                    ''' THEN hours END) `', worked_date, '`'))
      INTO @sql
      FROM table1;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user, ', @sql, ' 
                         FROM table1 
                        GROUP BY user');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it:

```sql
CALL user_worked_hours();
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a9ea9/1)

Comment: Wow thank you for that and i am trying to use your stored procedure example but my sql version is 5.5 and it does not run.... or am i missing something.?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run"?